# How do I stop my function from entering a value into every list?

Tags: python, list

For my assignment, I need to insert a value into a particular index in a sublist of a list which contains 3 lists. Instead of changing the value in only 1 sublist, it changes it in every sublist.

I have tried reentering the values which are used to determine the indices.

```py
def make_move(cur, move, player):
  m0 = move[0]
  m1 = move[1]
  cur[m0][m1] = player
make_move(world, (1,0), 'X')
print(world)
```

I expect the output to be:

```py
[['', '', ''], ['X', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

What I am receiving is:

```py
[['X', '', ''], ['X', '', ''], ['X', '', '']]
```

I made the world function as follows:

```py
def set_up_game(size):
  n = 0
  num = 0
  s = int(get_game_size(size))
  game = []
  rows = []
  columns = ''
  while n < s:
    rows.append(columns)
    n += 1
  while num < s:
    game.append(rows)
    num += 1

  return game
```

Comment: You should show how you made the `world` list. It looks like it contains three references to the same list.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
game.append(rows)
```

Change it to:

```
game.append(list(rows))
```

Which will create new lists within the `game` list.

---

What you did initially (with the while loop) is equivalent to:

```
game = [row] * num
```

You can see the problem with doing that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).